# Como pegar imagens de uma pasta no Android?

Tags: android

Fiz um exemplo de um `ListView` em que é usado `ArrayList` para preencher os `TextView` e `ImageView`. Porém estou melhorando ele pegando dados de um banco MySQL, com relação aos `TextView tudo certo, porém como eu faria para puxar as imagens, eu não queria colocar as imagens no banco e sim carregar para o dispositivo móvel que irá usar o APK.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta no caso você quer baixar as imagens para o aplicativo?

Comment: Isso mesmo @claudsan, queria mandar as imagens pro aplicativo, não sei se estou certo, mas para isso seria só eu jogar na pasta drawable, certo? porém como faço para ter um índice para buscar as imagens na hora de popular a listview? Deixa mostrar como estou fazendo na opção manual:

Comment: `    public static final Integer[] images = {
     R.drawable.img1,
     R.drawable.img2,
     R.drawable.img3,
     R.drawable.img4};`

Comment: @JamesOrtiz A pasta `res/drawable/` é usada para guardar arquivos que são incluídos lá em tempo de projeto, e não em tempo de execução do aplicativo. Em outras palavras, você não conseguirá guardar nela imagens que seu aplicativo baixa. Ao baixar uma imagem do banco, você terá que salvá-la num arquivo no sistema de arquivos do aparelho (memória interna ou sd card).

Comment: @Piovezan a melhor maneira então seria armazenar as imagens no MYSQL?

Comment: @JamesOrtiz Primeiro você afirmou que as imagens viriam de um servidor remoto (MySQL), agora está perguntando se é a melhor forma de armazenar? No servidor remoto você pode guardar da forma que preferir, em banco de dados ou como arquivo mesmo, disponível a partir de um link para uma imagem ou até mesmo como retorno de um webservice (REST por exemplo).

Comment: @Piovezan, acho que me expressei mal, peço desculpas. Eu tenho o banco de dados porém só com texto e gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de trabalhar com as imagens. Achei interessante a ideia do link, vou pesquisar se acho alguma ajuda no Google sobre isso. Grato

Comment: @JamesOrtiz Acho melhor a idéia do link mesmo, e também no caso do texto é melhor que venha via webservice. Fazer o aplicativo se conectar a um banco remoto não é recomendado, é melhor que o webservice faça isso e disponibilize em algum formato (JSON, XML, texto puro ou dados binários, conforme o caso).

Comment: @JamesOrtiz Da uma olhada aqui http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549421/how-to-download-and-save-an-image-in-android esta em inglês mas tem o exemplo completo acho que vai servir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não poderá guardar as imagens baixadas pelo seu aplicativo na pasta `res/drawable/` porque ela é destinada a guardar imagens disponíveis para o aplicativo em tempo de projeto, isto é, antes dele ser compilado. Terá que baixá-las de algum lugar e guardá-las no sistema de arquivos do seu aparelho, seja na memória interna ou no sd card. Além disso, fazer seu aplicativo se conectar diretamente a um banco de dados remoto para obter dados não é recomendado, é melhor deixar essa conexão a cargo de um webservice (REST por exemplo) que irá disponibilizar esses dados para o aplicativo por meio de uma URL.

Comment: Com certeza é uma das melhores opções para @JamesOrtiz